# How to Use SelfJoin in Jooq?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Can we use SelfJoin in JOOQ?

```sql
Select Count(1) CountPayments 
From PaymentDetail APD1, PaymentDetail APD2, Payment AP 
where APD1.PaymentNumber =123 
  and APD1.BillNumber > 0 
  and APD2.BillNumber = APD1.BillNumber 
  and APD2.PaymentNumber <> APD1.PaymentNumber 
  and AP.PaymentNumber = APD2.PaymentNumber
```

If Yes how can we use it in Above Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The manual's section about aliasing tables](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/aliased-tables/) might give you some clues.

Essentially, just assign aliases to your tables:

```java
PaymentDetail APD1 = PaymentDetail.as("APD1");
PaymentDetail APD2 = PaymentDetail.as("APD2");
Payment AP = Payment.as("AP");

DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(count(1).as("CountPayments"))
   .from(APD1, APD2, AP)
   .where(APD1.PaymentNumber.eq(123))
   .and(APD1.BillNumber.gt(0))
   .and(APD2.BillNumber.eq(APD1.BillNumber))
   .and(APD2.PaymentNumber.ne(APD1.PaymentNumber))
   .and(AP.PaymentNumber.eq(APD2.PaymentNumber))
```